# Returning my JSON Array from android thread to class

Tags: android, json, arraylist

Ok I'll do my best to explain this.

I created a thread to generate an Arraylist from a JSON URL. I want to return this to my main thread. I was considering using a global array but apparently this is bad practice.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LoadJson generate = new LoadJson();
    GenerateDataset.thread.start();
}
```

As you can see I call my run thread in my class Generate which starts to create my Object Arraylist. How would I be best to return this dataset to my original thread.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Arraylist<elements> temp = Start(); //<----- this list is what I want to return
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hold a `MutableLiveData<Arraylist<elements>>` in your GenerateDataset class that the thread will have access to.

In your MainActivity observe the LiveData and update the UI.

[about LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)